# How to group data by different date period in sql?

Tags: sql, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

How to group data by different date period in sql?

For example, I want the data to be grouped from `1/2/2015` to `6/2/2015`, `7/2/2015` to `12/2/2015` etc. So far I could only group them according to 1 date range by using the WHERE condition.

```
SELECT type, count(*) 
from table1 
WHERE Day(datefield) <=6 
Group by type
```

table1:

type, datefield

typeA, '2015-2-1'

typeB, '2015-2-2'

typeB, '2015-2-9'

typeA, '2015-2-18'

typeB, '2015-2-28'

desired result:

type, no. for day 1-6, no. for day 7-12, no. for day 13-18, no. for day 19-24, no. for day 25-31

type A, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0

type B, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desired result

Comment: You will probably need to use a windowing function like NTile: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx

Comment: But like @NoDisplayName said, some sample data and expected result would help make that determination...

Comment: desired result as shown above. Am doing it on report builder 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

First create a derived table where each datefield is replaced by a label ('1-6','7-12',etc.).
Then group that table by its label and type and get the counts. Finally pivot the labels into columns
using conditional aggregation (`max(case when ...`).

```
select type,
    max(case when date_label = '1-6' then date_count end) '1-6',
    max(case when date_label = '7-12' then date_count end) '7-12',
    max(case when date_label = '13-18' then date_count end) '13-18',
    max(case when date_label = '19-24' then date_count end) '19-24',
    max(case when date_label = '25-31' then date_count end) '25-31',
from (
    select 
        type, 
        date_label,
        count(*) date_count
    from
        (select type,
        case when day(datefield) <=6 then '1-6'
        when day(datefield) <= 12 then '7-12'
        when day(datefield) <= 18 then '13-18'
        when day(datefield) <= 24 then '19-24'
        when day(datefield) <= 31 then '25-31'
        else 'n/a' end as date_label
        from table1) t1
    group by type, date_label
) t1 group by type
```